# Loop through 2 folders and perform raster calculation

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, iteration

I am currently learning arcgis and python.

The problem includes looping through 2 folders (with rasters of same filename) and performing raster calculation on each raster pair. Below is my code:

```
import arcpy, os, glob  
from arcpy.sa import *  
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")  

ws1 = "E:\clip_qx"  
ws2 = "E:\clip_qy"  

outws = "E:\result"

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()  
for r in ws1:  
    r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster(r)  
    r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(ws2, basename))  
    result = sqrt ( r1^2 + r2^2 )  
    outname = basename    
    result.save(os.path.join(outws, outname))
```

However, I am getting an error. It seems that the rasters were not read.

```
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset E does not exist or is not supported.
```

Comment: Change your directory strings to raw format `w1 = r"E:\clip_qx"`. Python interprets the backslash in a string as an indicator of a special character.

Comment: also `basename` isn't defined. You probably mean `r` (the file name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating through the string `ws1`, instead of your list of rasters. Hence `'E'` as not a supported input (the first character in string `ws1`). You need to create a list of rasters by setting the workspace and then using `arcpy.ListRasters ()`. Try:

```
import arcpy, os, math
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")  

ws1 = r"E:\clip_qx"  
ws2 = r"E:\clip_qy"  

outws = r"E:\result"

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = ws1

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

for r in rasterlist:  
    r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster (r)  
    r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(ws2, r))  
    result = math.sqrt ( r1^2 + r2^2 )      
    result.save(os.path.join(outws, r))
```

However, this line will fail because you're trying to use python math operations on raster data:

`result = math.sqrt ( r1^2 + r2^2 )`

Look into raster math to learn how to execute this.

Comment: There seems to be wrong with the combination of rasters that were calculated.


[Kindly check this out](https://ibb.co/cZSoUv)

Comment: It's working now. Mistake on my end. Thanks again @Emil

Answer (score 0):

are you doing some kind of ocean or wind modeling? i was lucky to find your question because i am dealing with the same issue.

i got the math function to work by:

```
import arcpy, os, math
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```

and

```
result =  SquareRoot(r1 * r1 + r2 * r2)
```